# Zoom Page only in Crystal Report Viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, crystal-reports

I am facing a problem while I want to zoom in or out a report on a asp page. I have added the crystal report viewer in panel and added scroll bars to it but

when I zoom in the whole viewer zooms in

[image: Zoomed in]

and when I zoom out whole viewer zooms out

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Properties for your Crystal Reports Viewer, set the "Best Fit Page" property to False and it will only zoom the report page and not the whole page.

Comment: Woah .. and it was this simple .. Thanks .. Marked as Answer

Comment: Sometimes it just is!  ;)